# Is Refund Consulting legal?

Tags: legal, usa, eu

Is 'Refund Consulting' legal in the US and Europe?

I have been doing some research about Refund Consulting, but I've not been able to answer this question to my satisfaction.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is Refund Consulting and why would it not be legal?

Comment: @morsor - I've explained what it is in my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Refund consulting (e.g. telling people that you can help them to locate lost or unclaimed money or property, in return for a fee or a percentage of the money claimed) is, as far as I'm aware, perfectly legal in both the US and Europe.

- There are multiple organisations doing it in the US;
  https://unclaimed.org/
- And in the UK; https://unclaimedassets.co.uk/, https://www.uar.co.uk/, etc

That being said, you'd need to be extremely careful about what you're saying to potential clients. In the UK, telling a customer that they're '*guaranteed*' (or even '*likely*') to receive a return as a result of their search would be highly deceptive and would fall into the general description of financial fraud.